# AWS CloudWatch Agent Metric Error - The values for parameter id in MetricDataQueries are not unique

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to get metric data from `MetricDataQueries` in Lambda using CloudWatch Agent.

```
metrics_response = cw.get_metric_data(
        MetricDataQueries = metrics_data_queries,
        StartTime = datetime.now()+timedelta(minutes=-60),
        EndTime=datetime.now()
        )
```

The `metrics_data_queries` JSON is as below.

```
[{"Id": "cpu_time_idle", "MetricStat": {"Metric": {"Namespace": "CWAgent", "MetricName": "cpu_time_idle", 
"Dimensions": [{"Name": "InstanceId", "Value": "i-XXXX"}, {"Name": "cpu", "Value": "cpu0"}]}, "Period": 6000, "Stat": "Average"}, 
"Label": "cpu_time_idleResponse", "ReturnData": True}, 

{"Id": "cpu_time_idle", "MetricStat": {"Metric": {"Namespace": "CWAgent", "MetricName": "cpu_time_idle", 
"Dimensions": [{"Name": "InstanceId", "Value": "i-XXXX"}]}, 
"Period": 6000, "Stat": "Average"}, "Label": "cpu_time_idleResponse", "ReturnData": True}, 

{"Id": "cpu_time_active", "MetricStat": {"Metric": {"Namespace": "CWAgent", "MetricName": "cpu_time_active", 
"Dimensions": [{"Name": "InstanceId", "Value": "XXXX"}, {"Name": "cpu", "Value": "cpu0"}]}, 
"Period": 6000, "Stat": "Average"}, "Label": "cpu_time_activeResponse", "ReturnData": True}, 

{"Id": "cpu_time_active", "MetricStat": {"Metric": {"Namespace": "CWAgent", "MetricName": "cpu_time_active", 
"Dimensions": [{"Name": "InstanceId", "Value": "i-XXXX"}]}, 
"Period": 6000, "Stat": "Average"}, "Label": "cpu_time_activeResponse", "ReturnData": True}]
```

The Error Says :-

```
[ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the GetMetricData operation: **The values for parameter id in MetricDataQueries are not unique.**

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 27, in lambda_handler
    metrics_response = get_metrics(metrics_list_response,cw)
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 81, in get_metrics
    metrics_response = cw.get_metric_data(
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 391, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 719, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
```

Looks like because of duplicate Id, the `get_metric_data` is failing. **How to avoid the duplicate Ids ?** This metrics are derived from a CWAgent using below config.json

```
{
        "agent": {
                "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
                "run_as_user": "root"
        },
        "metrics": {
                "aggregation_dimensions": [
                        [
                                "InstanceId"
                        ]
                ],
                "append_dimensions": {
                        "InstanceId": "${aws:InstanceId}"
                },
                "metrics_collected": {
                        "collectd": {
                                "metrics_aggregation_interval": 60
                        },
                        "disk": {
                                "measurement": [
                                        "total",
                                        "used",
                                        "free",
                                        "used_percent"                          
                                ],
                                "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
                                "resources": [
                                        "/"
                                ]
                        },
                        "cpu": {
                                "measurement": [
                                        "time_active",
                                        "time_idle",
                                        "usage_active",
                                        "usage_idle",
                                        "usage_user",
                                        "usage_system"
                                ],
                                "totalcpu": false,
                                "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
                                "resources": [
                                        "*"
                                ]
                        },
                        "mem": {
                                "measurement": [
                                        "total",
                                        "used",
                                        "active",
                                        "available",
                                        "available_percent",
                                        "free",
                                        "inactive",
                                        "used_percent",
                                        "cached"
                                ],
                                "metrics_collection_interval": 60
                        },
                        "processes": {
                                "measurement": [
                                        "total",
                                        "running",
                                        "sleeping",
                                        "blocked",
                                        "dead"                          
                                ],
                                "metrics_collection_interval": 60
                        }
                        
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's complaining about the `Id` parameters `"Id": "cpu_time_idle"` and `"Id": "cpu_time_active"`. They need to be unique but the first two are the same and the second two are the same.

You can just change that in the request to `cpu_time_idle_1`,  `cpu_time_idle_2`, `cpu_time_active_1` and `cpu_time_active_2`. Ids don't need to be the same as metric names, you can keep the metric names as they are and just change the Ids.

Comment: Thanks so much @Dejan. Appreciate your help!